# Optim-nonlinear equation in matlab code

Tags: matlab

I updated the question to clarify it more. Here is a graph:

For the curve in the attached photo, I hope to draw the curve. I have its equation and it is after simplification will be like this one

```
% Eq-2
    (b*Y* cos(v) + c    -  k*X*sin(v))^2 + ...
sqrt(k*X*(cos(v) + 1.0) +  b*Y*sin(v))^2) - d = 0.0
```

Where:

```
v = atan((2.0*Y)/X) + c
```

and `b`, `c`, `d` and `k` are constants.

from the attached graph,

The curve is identified in two points:

```
p1 @ (x=0)
p2 @ (y=0)
```

I a new on coding so accept my apologize if my question is not clear.

Thanks

Comment: If it is a semi-parabola, why don't you implement the classic linear form Y = a*x^2 + b*x + c (assuming that the symmetry axis of the parabola is parallel to Y, a>0 if it is concave, b = 0 if the vertex lies exactly on Y axis) ? (I am thinking how to answer in your case)

Comment: It is not really parabolic. As I could not attach an image I wanted to calrify the curve shape. we have its equation and the boundris.

Comment: You forgot to ask a question.

Comment: If I look at your original equation 2 (before your edit) and simplify, I arrive at a different equation than the one that is in the question now...Can you please check?

Comment: (see my updated answer)

Comment: (see my new an improved answer ☺)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I was having fun with this (thanks for that)!

Different question, different answer.

The solution below first searches for the constants causing the `X` and `Y` intercepts you were looking for (`p1` and `p2`). For those constants that best fit the problem, it makes a plot, taking into account numerical issues.

In fact, you don't need eq. 1, because that's true always for any curve -- it's just there to confuse you, and problematic to use.

So, here it is:

```
function C = solve_for_F()

    % Points of interest
    px = 6;
    py = 4.2;

    % Wrapper function; search for those constants 
    % causing the correct X,Y intercepts (at px, py)
    G = @(C) abs(F( 0, px, C)) + ... % X intercept at px
             abs(F(py,  0, C));      % Y intercept at py

    % Initial estimate, based on your original equation
    C0 = [5/33
          1247745517111813/562949953421312
          4243112111277797/4503599627370496
          5/66];

    % Minimize the error in G by optimizing those constants
    C = fminsearch(G, C0);

    % Plot the solutions
    plot_XY(px, py, C);

end

function plot_XY(xmax,ymax, C)

    % graininess of X
    N = 100;

    % Find solutions for all alphae
    Y       = zeros(1,N);
    X       = linspace(0, xmax, N);
    y0      = linspace(ymax, 0, N);
    options = optimset('Display', 'off',...,...
                       'TolX'   , 1e-10);

    % Solve the nonlinear equation for each X
    for ii = 1:numel(X)

        % Wrapper function for fzero()
        fcn1 = @(y)F(y, X(ii), C);

        % fzero() is probably the fastest and most intuitive 
        % solver for this problem
        [Y(ii),~,flag] = fzero(fcn1, y0(ii), options);

        % However, it uses an algorithm that easily diverges
        % when the function slope is large. For those cases, 
        % solve with fminsearch()
        if flag ~= 1

            % In this case, the minimum of the absolute value
            % is searched for (which should be zero)
            fcn2 = @(y) abs(fcn1(y));

            Y(ii) = fminsearch(fcn2, y0(ii), options);
        end

    end

    % Now plot the X,Y solutions
    plot(X, Y,...
        'linewidth', 2,...
        'color',     [1 0.65 0]);    
    xlabel('X'), ylabel('Y')
    axis([0 xmax+.1 0 ymax+.1])

end

function fval = F(Y, X, C)

    % Unpack constants
    b = C(1);  d = C(3);
    c = C(2);  k = C(4);

    % pre-work
    V = atan2(2*Y, X) + c;

    % Eq. 2
    fval = sqrt( (b*Y*sin(V) + k*X*(cos(V) + 1))^2 + ...
                 (b*Y*cos(V) - k*X* sin(V)     )^2  ) - d;
end
```

[image: solution]

Answer (score 1):

So, after your edit, it is a bit more clear what you want.

I insist that your equation needs work -- the original equation (before your edit) simplified to what I have below. The curve for that looks like your plot, except the `X` and `Y` intercepts are at different locations, and funky stuff happens near `X = 0` because you have numerical problems with the tangent (you might want to reformulate the problem).

But, after checking your equation, the following code should be helpful:

```
function solve_for_F()

    % graininess of alpha
    N = 100;

    % Find solutions for all alphae
    X       = zeros(1,N);
    options = optimset('Display', 'off');    
    alpha   = linspace(0, pi/2, N);
    x0      = linspace(6, 0, N);

    for ii = 1:numel(alpha)    
        X(ii) = fzero(@(x)F(x, alpha(ii)), x0(ii), options);
    end

    % Convert and make an X-Y plot
    Y = X .* tan(alpha);

    plot(X, Y,...
        'linewidth', 2,...
        'color',     [1 0.65 0]);

end

function fval = F(X, alpha)

    Y = X*tan(alpha);

    % Please, SIMPLIFY in the future
    A = 1247745517111813/562949953421312;
    B = 4243112111277797/4503599627370496;
    V = atan2(2*Y,X) + A;

    eq2 = sqrt(  (5/33*( Y*sin(V) + X/2*(cos(V) + 1) ))^2 + ...
                 (5/33*( Y*cos(V) - X/2* sin(V)      ))^2  ) - B;

    fval = eq2;

end
```

Results:

[image: plot results]

Comment: Thank you Rody, for your effort. I updated the question. many thanks again

Comment: @AD_Matlab: In fact, the `X` and `Y` intercepts depend crucially on the values of those constants...That is not part of the question, right? Or do you want to find constants `[b c d k]` that solve for `p1` and `p2`? That is a different question altogether...

Comment: Dear Rody, I do really appreciate your time and help. the constant b,c,d,k is constant in the equation as that you have used (A,B,C). However, I can see typos in Eq-2, and V, I repeat the simplified as follows :  A=1247745517111813/562949953421312;
B=4243112111277797/4503599627370496;
V=atan((2*KII)/KI)+A ;                                                                                               eqn = sqrt ((5/33*y*sin(V) + (5*X*(cos(V) + 1)) /66 )^2 +
((5/33*y*cos(V)) - 5/66*x*sin (V))^2) - B==0

Comment: I think we need first cancel the alpha from the problem as its assumed and does not seem fit with the criterion (eq-2). what is clear is the intercept points.                                                                               if we can create an exterior loop from 0: Y-intercept (say 4.2), and an interior loop from X=0: X=intercept (say 6). then x,y solved inside the loop by optimization. In this case, our plot defined by curve envelope (Eq-2), and both X, Y intercept. Do you think if we excluding alpha, and use the loops for the X, and Y intercepts , can plot the curve, please?.

Comment: @AD_Matlab Have you seen my second answer?

Comment: Yes, I just comment on. I think there is typo in the equation in your code so the equation has been presented again. also, what you think  about my suggestion of using loops for x,y. is it work, please?

Comment: Oh, Rody, I just seen it, it looks great. I will apply it on my criterion for a check. so many thanks. appreciated

Comment: @AD_Matlab well I've corrected the equation in my second answer; the +1 term is there now. In the second answer, there is no alpha, and what you're suggesting is exactly what I'm doing, so...

Comment: Rody,  apologize for my bad.  That right it looks alpha that i assumed from curve does not work. I will combine your code in my procedure sheet, and check all. many thanks

Comment: @AD_Matlab you're welcome :) You can mark my answer as accepted, helps both me and the forum stats